# Find f(x) $\int_0^x f(u)du - f'(x) = x$

Tags: laplace-transform, integro-differential-equations

Find f(x)

$$\int_0^x f(u)du - f'(x) = x$$

I was not given f(0) which makes it difficult for me to find f(x). This is what I have thus far:

$$\frac{F(p)}{p}-pF(p)+f(0)=\frac{1}{p^2}$$
$$\frac{F(p)}{p}-pF(p)=\frac{1}{p^2}-f(0)$$
$$F(p)(\frac{1}{p}-p)=\frac{1}{p^2}-f(0)$$
$$F(p)=\frac{\frac{1}{p^2}-f(0)}{(\frac{1}{p}-p)}$$

Can I even take the Inverse Laplace to get f(x) or do I have to do something entirely different. Once again I was not given f(0). And I used the formula:

$$L(\int_0^t f(u)du)=\frac{1}{p} F(p)$$

where L=Laplace Transform

Comment: You guys were all very helpful but I think my teacher wants me to use Laplace instead of FTC. But I will do it both ways instead just to be sure.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that using Laplace transform is an obligation here? I am asking because using this approach only complicates things in the present case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{x}f(u)\space\text{d}u-f'(x)=x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[\int_{0}^{x}f(u)\space\text{d}u-f'(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[x\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[\int_{0}^{x}f(u)\space\text{d}u\right]_{(s)}-\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[f'(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_{x}\left[x\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{f(s)}{s}-sf(s)+f(0)=\frac{1}{s^2}\Longleftrightarrow f(s)\left[\frac{1}{s}-s\right]=\frac{1}{s^2}-f(0)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$f(s)=\frac{\frac{1}{s^2}-f(0)}{\frac{1}{s}-s}\Longleftrightarrow f(s)=\frac{1-f(0)s^2}{s-s^3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[f(s)\right]_{(x)}=\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1-f(0)s^2}{s-s^3}\right]_{(x)}\Longleftrightarrow f(x)=1+(f(0)-1)\text{cosh}(x)$$

Comment: it is f'(x) not f(x) for the original problem

Comment: @geeking4math I've edited my answer

Comment: wouldn't it be $\frac{f(s)}{s}-(sf(s)-f(0))=\frac{f(s)}{s}-sf(s)+f(0)$

Comment: @geeking4math Yes, you're right, and notice that $f(0)$ can be a constant!

Comment: okay, thank you!! I think that was my biggest worry, whether  or not it can be a constant, however, would if it is not??

Comment: Do you know the proof of the laplace transform of $y'(t)$?

Comment: yes i do. It's kinda of foggy because I learned it last year however I am pretty sure I can do it again if I just use the Laplace Transform equation and solve.

Comment: can you explain to me how you did the last step, the inverse laplace. are there easy laplace inverses I can use or do I have to do this completely by hand?

Comment: @geeking4math You can use online tools or there are a lot of lists online with standard forms. In this example use partial fractions

Answer (score 6):

A start: Differentiate. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,we have $f(x)-f''(x)=1$. Solve this differential equation.

By substituting in the original equation, we can see  that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto 1$ is a particular solution so it suffices to find the homogeneous solutions. +1

Comment: A note on the answer: Note that $f(\star)$ is differentiable, hence continuous, and that's why the FTC is appliable.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I add done a mistake in my previous answer (taking $f(0)=0$ instead of $f'(0)=0$). It is corrected in this version:

Taking $x=0$, one finds

$$f'(0)=0  \ \ (1)$$

Thus this integro-differential equation is equivalent, by derivation, to

$$f(x)-f''(x)=1 \ \ \text{with condition (1)}$$

which has solution

$$1+Ae^{x}+Be^{-x} \ \ \text{with condition (1)}$$

(particular solution of the diff. equ. + general solution of the homogeneous associated diff. equ. $f(x)-f''(x)=0$.)

Taking (1) into account, and because $f'(x)=Ae^{x}-Be^{-x}$, we have $f'(0)=A-B=0$; thus, the solution to the question is:

$$f(x)=1+Ae^{x}+Ae^{-x}=1+a\cosh{x}$$

$a$ being an arbitrary real constant.

Of course, treating the initial equation by Laplace Transform yields the same results (as confirmed by the result of @Jan Eerland)

Comment: are you able to do it by Laplace Transform??